# How can move the file and change the file extension with simple bash?

Tags: bash, move, file-extension

Select file which contains `sqlite` in my current directory:

```
ls | grep sqlite
null and empty string in sqlite.txt
pythoin write None into sqlite.txt
```

Move them into `/tmp` directory:

```
ls |grep sqlite |xargs -i mv {}  /tmp
ls /tmp | grep sqlite
null and empty string in sqlite.txt
pythoin write None into sqlite.txt
```

How can move them into `/tmp` and change the file extension as `rst` at the same time?

```
ls |grep sqlite | some_simple_bash_command
```

After executing it:

```
ls /tmp | grep sqlite
null and empty string in sqlite.rst
pythoin  write None   into sqlite.rst
```

@David C. Rankin,`grep sqlite *` can't work at all!

[image]

Comment: Learn not to pipe `ls`. It's `grep 'sqlite' *` or to move it is simply `mv *sqlite* /tmp`... To move and change extension, then its `for f in *sqlite*; do mv "$f" "${f%.old}.new"; done` (add `"/tmp/${f%.old}.new"` to set the destination dir to `/tmp`). Or to only operate on the results of `grep` and change extension, use a *process substitution* to feed a `while` loop, e.g. `while read -r f; do mv "$f" "${f%.old}.new"; done < <(grep 'sqlite' *)`  (note the space between `< <` -- required -- same note on adding `"/tmp/"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
for f in *sqlite*; do
    mv -v -- "$f" "/tmp/${f%.*}.rst"
done
```

- `*sqlite*` expands to the list of files in the current directory that contain the string `sqlite` anywhere in their names.  See the [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) section of the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).
- `${f%.*}` expands to the value of `$f` with any suffix removed.  See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string).
- The `--` argument to `mv` is to ensure proper handling of files whose names begin with `-`.  See [Bash Pitfalls #2 (cp $file $target)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target).

Answer (score 0):

Let's expand on the comment a bit. First, learn not to pipe `ls` to the utility you want to use. All utilities that operate on files will accept a list of filenames through *file-globbing*. So to `grep` all files in the *present working directory* containing `"sqlite"` it's just:

```bash
$ grep 'sqlite' *
```

To change a filename extension POSIX provides a *parameter expansion with substring removal* that allows you to trim from the right, e.g. `${var%pattern}`, to trim to the last occurrence of `pattern` beginning from the right it is `${var%%pattern}`. Note: `pattern` can contain normal file-globbing such as `?` or `*`.

To trim from the left it is `${var#pattern}` and `${var##pattern}`, respectively. These are POSIX expansions meaning they are available in all POSIX shells. Bash on the other hand provides many, many more expansions (stuff between `${...}`) that only work in bash (referred to as `"bashisms"`) Use POSIX when available to solve your problem for maximum portability.

To change the extension of a filename stored in the variable `"$f"`, it would be:

```bash
mv "$f" "${f%.old}.new"`
```

Where `old` and `new` are the old and new file extensions.

When you want to rename or move and rename all files that result from a glob selection (e.g. using `pattern*` or the like, a `for` loop is what you need, e.g to select all files in the current directory whose name begins with `pattern` you can use `pattern*` in

```bash
for f in pattern*; do
  printf "%s\n" "$f"
done
```

(which simply prints the filename)

To move all files beginning with `pattern` to the `/tmp` directory, it would be:

```bash
for f in pattern*; do
  mv "$f" /tmp
done
```

(note: `xargs` would do just fine here)

When you want to process files that are the result of running some other process or utility, bash provides *process substitution* allowing you to feed a `while` loop in the form of `while read -r var; do #stuff with "$var"; done < <(process)`. In your example of `grep sqlite` to move all files returned to `/tmp` while changing the extension from `old` to `new`, that would be:

```bash
while read -r f; do
  mv "$f" "/tmp/${f%.old}.new"
done < <(grep 'sqlite' *)
```

(for POSIX shells you would pipe the result of `grep` to your `while` loop, e.g. `grep 'sqlite' * | while read -r f ...`)

Look things over and let me know if you have questions or if I missed the intent of your question.

Comment: `grep   'sqlite'  *` can't work!

Comment: Really -- and why not? You are searching all files in the present working directory for the string `sqlite` -- which it what you describe needing.... @showkey -- prove it to yourself, e.g. `printf "foo\nsqlite\nbar\n" > a; printf "foo\nsqlite\nbar\n" > b; grep -d skip 'sqlite' *` and the result??? `a:sqlite` and `b:sqlite` just as expected...

Comment: And please point out anything in the answer that is technically incorrect. If you need to trim the match from the return from grep, that is as simple as `"${f%%:*}"`, e.g. `while read -r f; do f="${f%%:*}"; echo "$f"; done < <(grep -d skip 'sqlite' *)` -- which given the example in the previous comment outputs `a` and `b` -- as expected.